# Got a Software Developer job offer, but didn't tell I haven't obtained my degree yet

Tags: job-offer, software-development, europe

**TL;DR**: I have a job offer but I haven't passed the final oral exam yet due to personal reasons, which I didn't mention to them earlier and now they're asking for a copy of the degree.

I live somewhere in western Europe.
I worked as a junior Software Developer with an apprenticeship contract for 2 years. (1 school week every month).

Near the end of my contract (mid January), I was supposed to do a presentation in front of a jury that will decide whether I get the diploma or not. However due to depression I didn't prepare it and delayed it to the next session in summer.

I applied for jobs anyway. My resume mentions the apprenticeship program, school, and the degree, but it does not explicitly mention I obtained it. I rarely got asked about it and never brought it up myself.

This is how it appears in my resume:

> **School name (month/year to month/year)**
>   Software Developer professional certification
>   * school program content

I received 2 job offers and I accepted one after a very fast and simple interview process (technical test, phone interview, final interview at their office). *They did not ask about my diploma, and I didn't bring it up.*

Now they're asking for a bunch of documents to draft my contract, one of which is my degree.

**How do I tell them I delayed the jury for personal reasons, without inspiring doubt?**

I already have a chaotic resume due to my depression, and I am usually a shy person, I am worried they will doubt me and retract the offer.

Comment: Did your resume say you have a degree already?

Comment: Does your resume say that you got the degree? Or did you say that you do?

Comment: My resume says I was in an apprenticeship program for that degree until the end of January. There is no explicit mention, but it would be expected that I obtained it.
I never told them I obtained the degree, only that my apprenticeship contract ended recently.

Comment: @StartledTurtle regardless of the outcome, change your CV now!

Comment: It might be helpful to show how you mentioned your degree. There is no telling who made the mistake based on your current question, so it's difficult to answer how to proceed. If it's in the following format for example "school-name, Bachelor in IT: 2004-present day"  then you'd want to clear up the CV. not admit to a mistake you didn't make. if you basically just went "Degree: Bachelors in IT" yeah then you just lied, and it's time to apologize.

Comment: @BobMeijer it is in this format :  
**<School name> (<month/year> to <month/year>)** _(new line)_
Software Developer professional certification _(new line)_
<school program content>
  
I started applying long before school ended and didn't think too much of it. :/

Comment: Adding "expected [date]" after a degree is a good strategy when you are job hunting near the end of a degree program.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> With no mention on my resume of not having passed the jury yet. I rarely got asked about it and never brought it up myself.

So you put the degree on your resume without actually mentioning the trifling detail that you hadn't actually finished it? Well, I can't possibly see how *that* would come back to bite you in ass..

> Now they're asking for a bunch of documents to draft my contract, one of which is my degree.

Oops. Clearly they are under the impression that you actually have the degree you claim on your resume, and unless your CV makes it clear that you haven't actually finished your degree yet I can't exactly blame them,

> I am worried they will doubt me and retract the offer.

This is, sadly, a realistic fear. About all you can do is explain that you had expected to have the degree completed by this point but that due to health reasons at the time your final presentation has been delayed to the summer and that you expect to be able to forward the appropriate documentation in due course.

I'm not going to sugar coat this though - it's going to look like a pretty weak cover for lying on your resume and hoping you'd never actually have to prove your degree. They *might* not be too fussed, or they might kick your application to the curb. Given they are asking for proof of the degree as part of the on-boarding it's looking rather likely that the degree is going to be considered essential to the offer.

Comment: As brutal as it is, this is the correct answer. Lie by omission can be very serious. I would add that OP still has the 2nd job to go back to if things go wrong, possibly

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul: listing a non-existing degree is not lying by omission. It is just plain lying. Lying by omission would be e.g. - forgetting to mention that you broke some of your boss's bones. Or not mentioning that the previous job ended by being fired for misconduct (as opposed to quitting for personal reasons).

Comment: OP's only option is to apologise, tell them that he never intended to suggest that he already obtained the degree and that he will obtain it this summer. Whether that flies depends on what it exactly says on OP's CV.